# Convert update button on cart page from input to an anchor link in Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify, cart

On the cart page in Shopify I'd like to use an anchor link instead of an input button when user updates cart so that I can add an html icon using Font Awesome. I don't believe I can accomplish with a button.

Here's the current button:

```
<input type="submit" id="update-cart" class="btn" name="update" value="{{ 'cart.general.update' | t }}" style="float:right;"/>
```

I tried the following with no luck:

```
<a href="#" id="update-cart">Update <i class='fa fa-refresh' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `button` would definitely be the best solution here. I'm not sure why you believe it wouldn't work. Try this:

```
<button id="update-cart" class="btn" name="update" style="float: right;">
  {{ 'cart.general.update' | t }}
  <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Note that you should really add that inline style via a rule in an external stylesheet.

Comment: Didn't even think to use a `button`. That did the trick. Thank you!